# Can not push changes from local master branch to remote master branch

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to use git push herocu master but what all i am getting is 
![remote rejected] master->master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dncollector.git'
I also tried *git pull herocu master* but it also shows a fatal like *couldnt find remote ref master*.
Why is this happening?
I am working on windows.

Comment: I changed the tags according to the topic.  Probably just a typo (python → git).

Comment: Did you check the output of `git config -l | grep fetch` and `git config -l | grep url`? If your remote is correctly configured, you should have something along the lines of `remote.herocu.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/herocu/*` for the *fetch* config

Comment: Also, is it `herocu` or `heroku`? You seem to use both indifferently...

Comment: ya heroku it is . sorry for that . But i did the same but it tells grep is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet function @RomainVALERI

Comment: @yogesh Hmm, yes sorry I assumed you were in bash context but it seems you're not. But it was just a way to filter other irrelevant config lines. Do a normal config without grep and search for fetch and url lines

Comment: Ya i did the same again. I have got those highlighted lines on my screen which shows the proper configuration of the remote. @RomainVALERI

Comment: The message `pre-receive hook declined` means that the other Git is telling you it doesn't like your commits. It *should* tell you *why* it doesn't like your commits, but if it is particularly obnoxious and stubborn, it can just keep telling you to go away without telling you why. If that's the case, you just have to guess why.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed the code to remote origin. You can try and follow those command. Please make sure you had created one resposity.

```
1. git config --global user.name "yourname" 
2. git config --global user.email "youeremail" 
3. git init
4. git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:***.git
5. git push -u origin --all
```